# missing a quote somewhere T_String error

Tags: php

This is driving me crazy i know its a simple error but either i added or left out a quote something

```
echo "<option ". ($data['language'] == "" ? 'selected=selected>-- Select --</option>' : 'value=$data['language'] selected=selected'");
```

Comment: Do you need to escape the embedded double-quotes (")? I would have thought so, but I don't know php.

Comment: The entire statement does not make sense. First of all, 135 chars in one line are against most coding conventions. You are also missing a closing bracket around the first expression and your interpolation in the third expression is broken, too. But even when you fix those things and there is a language, your option tag will be incomplete. And unless you are using one of the HTML soups over XHTML, you are also missing quotes around your attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
echo "<option ". ($data['language'] == "" ? "selected=selected>-- Select --</option>" : "value=".$data['language']." selected=selected");
```

There was an inconsistant use of quotes/inline variable inclusion (so there was a ' where there should be a ")

Answer (score 1):

You can't do variable interpolation in single quotes, and especially when using single quotes as the delimiter.

```
echo "<option ". ($data['language'] == "" ? 'selected=selected>-- Select --</option>' : 'value=' . $data['language'] . ' selected=selected'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
'value=$data['language'] selected=selected'
```

Into:

```
'value="'.$data['language'].'" selected=selected'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option "
     . ($data['language'] == ""
     ? 'selected=selected>-- Select --</option>' :
     'value=$data['language'] selected=selected'" //< This line
     );
```

As you can see your using the same quotes as the selection from the $data array so you need to do:

```
echo "<option " . ($data['language'] == "") ? 'selected=selected>-- Select --</option>' : "value=\"" . $data['language'] . "\" \"selected=selected\"" );
```

a better solution would be:

```
if($data['language'] == "")
{
    echo '<option selected=selected>-- Select --</option>';
}else
{
    echo '<option selected=selected value="' . $data['language'] . '">-- Select --</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option ". ($data['language'] == "" ? "selected=selected>-- Select --</option>" : "value='".$data['language'] . "' selected=selected");
```